# multiple markers at this line

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I get the below error in the line `this.viewcam.setOnClickListerner(new view.OnClickListerner())`.
I get this error in eclipse.

Multiple markers at this line

- The method `setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)` in the type `View` is not applicable for the arguments (`new OnClickListener(){}`)
- view cannot be resolved to a type

```java
    public class Main extends Activity
    implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    Button viewcam;
    EditText editTextIp;
    EditText login;
    EditText passwd;
    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
    {
      super.onCreate(paramBundle);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      this.viewcam = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.viewcam));
      this.viewcam.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == this.viewcam)
      {
        Log.i("login", this.login.getText().toString());
        Log.i("Passwd", this.passwd.getText().toString());
        Intent localIntent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), MjpegSample.class);
        Log.i("My ip", this.editTextIp.getText().toString());
        localIntent1.putExtra("ip", "http://" +                 this.editTextIp.getText().toString() + "/");
        localIntent1.putExtra("user", this.login.getText().toString());
        localIntent1.putExtra("passwd", this.passwd.getText().toString());
        startActivityForResult(localIntent1, 1000);
      }     }
               });
 this.editTextIp = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip));
 this.login = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username));
 this.passwd = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password));

}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 this.viewcam.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {
```

To

```
 this.viewcam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize View in

```
this.viewcam.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {
```

so it should be

```
this.viewcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```